# How can i import view which bring a closure with itself in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Here is my code, it does not work:

```
struct ContainerView<MyContent: View>: View {

    let myContent: () -> MyContent
    @State private var myValue: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        myContent() { value in
            
            myValue = value
        }
        
    }

}
```

I want make this logic works, when I am bringing my view as myContent to body, I want be able to bring a string value with it like in code! I am not looking for reaching my goal with other ways, the goal of this question is be able to access `value` like in code as clouser.

Comment: Can you show how you intend on creating a `ContainerView`?

Comment: No, because I need to make ContainerView first!  Egg or chicken? which one is first?

Comment: That, plus your comment to jnpdx's answer, really sounds like you have no idea what you're doing, and that this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What problem are you trying to solve by achieving this?

Comment: The goal is making the logic works, nothing more and making use case of the logic. I know how i can send a string value as parameter to child view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning: I'm not sure what the use-case of this is -- it's not clear what problem is trying to be solved here, but there's likely a better fit that trying to make something like this work. This answer, though, does solve the compilation errors presented above.

---

Your syntax inside `body` implies that you want a trailing closure on `myContent`, but it's not defined in the signature. This would solve the compilation error:

```
struct ContainerView<MyContent: View>: View {

    let myContent: (@escaping (String) -> Void) -> MyContent
    @State private var myValue: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(myValue)
        myContent() { value in
            myValue = value
        }
    }
}
```

Call site:

```
ContainerView { closure in
  Button("Test") {
    closure("Value")
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks working, but how we can send the needed value to ContainerView from a ContentView? can you show the use case of ContainerView.

Comment: I can't show you the use case for ContainerView because I'm not clear on what the use case for any of this is. Are you trying to pass a value up from child to parent view? Is this something that a Binding or a PreferenceKey could solve?

Comment: No, reverse! If we say ContentView is parent and ContainerView is child and if we look the logic of code in question, the value should come from ContentView to ContainerView. Again the goal of question is making the logic works, otherwise I know how i can send a String value via parameter or any other ways.

Comment: Updated my answer with the call site -- maybe that's what you meant by "use case"? Otherwise, I'm not sure what you're asking.